# why this math mode in lettrine

Tags: fonts, math-mode, xetex, lettrine

Trying to use the [lettrine](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettrine) package in XeLaTeX with the Georg Duffner's EB Garamond font results in:

```
! Bad USV code (-2411)
```

Trial and error shows that the problem comes with these two lines in lettrine.sty:

```
\smash{\llap{\mbox{\L@ante}\raisebox{\L@lraise}{\usebox{\L@lbox}}%
       \hskip \the\L@Findent}}
```

These lines, in the original lettrine.sty file, are enclosed within `$ $` and thus typeset in math mode. I removed the `$ $` and the problem disappeared.

Question: Is there any reason why these two lines should be in math mode, given that they don't do anything about math?

Comment: I can't see any reason, and and the documented source doesn't give any clue. On the other hand the error indicates a badly encoded unicode input file. The math version of smash typesets the expression four times including script and scriptscript size so it may have caused some font loading code to be loaded, otherwise I can't see how the error could be affected by this.

Comment: Apparently, `lettrine`'s author thought that `\smash` works only in math mode, which is untrue.

Comment: FWIW, I've had a similar problem with EB Garamond, but without `lettrine.` I *suspect* the problem may lie in mt-EBGaramond.cfg (the microtype configuration), as renaming this file 'cures' the (my) problem, as does omitting microtype altogether. Using LuaTeX also cures.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently the author of `lettrine` was thinking that `\smash` works only in math mode. There *are* problems when using it outside math mode, since it doesn't start a paragraph as it could be expected. However the code in the definition of `\@lettrine` is

```
\def\@lettrine[#1]#2#3{%
  \setcounter{L@lines}{\theDefaultLines}%
  <...omitted code...>
  \noindent\leavevmode
  \parshape=\L@parshape
  $\smash{\llap{\mbox{\L@ante}\raisebox{\L@lraise}{\usebox{\L@lbox}}%
          \hskip \the\L@Findent}}$%
  \usebox{\L@tbox}}
```

and the `\noindent` would already make TeX switch to horizontal mode (and the `\leavevmode` is redundant). We can see that no math mode material is used in the argument to `\smash`.

Thus there's no risk in removing the `$`; but it's better to stop the search for other `\parshape` specifications that could cause `\smash` to be expanded prematurely. Thus I propose the following patch:

```
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@lettrine}{$}{\relax}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@lettrine}{$}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

that is, changing the first `$` into `\relax` and removing the second `$`.

The patch should do nothing if the `\@lettrine` macro is changed in a package revision (provided it doesn't inject `$` in other places of the same macro).

Comment: I agree with this analysis. I have just uploaded to CTAN a new version (1.64) correcting this bug following egreg's suggestions. Thanks to all of you!